# Jquery dynamic parameter

Tags: jquery

In a div tag `onclick=function(param)` I pass a dynamic parameter to jquery `function(cid)`. In alert I will get the value but while send to `data:{"ID":cid}` I do not get results.  How to pass parameter to data in jquery?

```
function CallService(cid) 
    {           
         var ClientID = {"ID": $('#txt_id').val()}
         $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#cn_content").html('');
            $("#cn_content").addClass("loading");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AdvService.asmx/GetCtcDetails1",
               // data: JSON.stringify(ClientID),
                data: {"ID":cid},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",         

                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });


       }

            function OnSuccess(data, status) {
            $("#cn_content").removeClass("loading");
            $("#cn_content").html(data);

        }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in the code you posted but in the code that calls the CallService-function. Do you assign that function directly as event-handler to the click-event? Notice that element.onClick=CallService(param)  won't work because that would assign the return value of CallService as click-handler, not the function itself.

Comment: Yes i passed  like below  HTML+='<div class="cn_item"  onclick ="CallService('+ i + '); return false;">' still i wont get result.i cant get what i pass that parameter in alert message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you define **OnError**. If it doesn't exists, the execution of $.ajax() will fail.

The rest looks fine, it should work.

Comment: I have function OnError(request, status, error) {
                $("#cn_content").removeClass("loading");
                $("#cn_content").html(request.statusText);
                $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
            } but its wont so any error message

Comment: I find Answer need to pass   data: JSON.stringify(ClientID),